# A few folders went missing after “Disk Not Ejected Properly” when my Mac went to sleep

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, data-recovery

I have an external hard disk in exFAT format (WD 500 GB WDBPCK5000ABK-03) for storing important documents.
Last week I plugged it to my Macbook Pro to view some documents. After viewing, I did not eject it but to put my Macbook to sleep instead.
Every time I wake my Macbook up, I get this “Disk Not Ejected Properly” message. The sleep and wake up cycle with the warning message happen for 4 times, then I realized 5 folders go missing.

I know something was wrong, and I stopped writing new data to this disk. I did the following things

- Searched the missing folders and filesin the `.Trashes` folder inside the external HDD
- Searched the missing folders and files in the Trash Bin in my Macbook
- Plugged my external HDD to a Windows computer and look for hidden
  folders and files
- Searched the missing folders in the `Recycling Bin`    of my Windows
- Used Recuva to scan for deleted files on my external HDD using Windows

The folders and files are nowhere to be seen. But Recuva gives me some strange results.

### These files belong to `My Work/Learning material`

[image]

### These files belong to `My Work/Sheet Music`

[image]

### These files belong to `My Work/Teaching material`

[image]

Only in the deep scanning mode do I find the missing three folders `My Work/Teaching material`, `My Work/Learning material`, and `My Work/Sheet Music`. But all these three folders are shown as `?` in the Recuva. Unfortunately there are 26,000 files like this, and 25,000 of them are unrecoverable since they are "Overwritten with D:?" according to Recuva.

What is this `?` in Recuva? Is it a sign that my HDD is dying?

I haven't been writing anything to my external HDD, why are there suddenly so many deleted files? Can they even be recovered if I went to data recovery center?

How sure if it is part of the problem, recently, I bought a **USB-C to Micro-B** to replace the original **USB 3.0 to Micro-B** cable.

Comment: exFAT is not a robust storage format for surviving unexpected ejection. Your best bet is to recover from your backup and this time format the disk as APFS.

Comment: And eject your drive before putting the Mac to sleep.